# Passing an image between activities

Tags: android, image, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

I would know what's wrong in my code:
When i clicked an item in my recyclerView it shows me only the two textViews but the image is never displayed.
I know that the error is that the image is a String so to get the image ,i cant use the method "getIntExtra" in the second activity.but i don't know how can i rectify this.
My data is stored in a firebase database.

**This is my class model:**

```
public class Dentist implements Parcelable {
    private String Nom;
    private String Adresse;
    private  String Image;

    protected Dentist(Parcel in) {
        Nom = in.readString ( );
        Adresse = in.readString ( );
        Image = in.readString ( );
    }

    public Dentist(String nom, String adresse ,String image) {
        this.Nom = nom;
        this.Adresse = adresse;
        this.Image = image;

    }

    public Dentist (){

    }

    public static final Creator<Dentist> CREATOR = new Creator<Dentist> ( ) {
        @Override
        public Dentist createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Dentist ( in );
        }

        @Override
        public Dentist[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Dentist[size];
        }
    };

    public String getNom() {
        return Nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        Nom = nom;
    }

    public String getAdresse() {
        return Adresse;
    }

    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        Adresse = adresse;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image ;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
         Image= image;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString ( Nom );
        dest.writeString ( Adresse );
        dest.writeString ( Image );
    }
}
```

**This is the first activity:**

```
 public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super ( itemView );
                TextNom = (TextView)itemView.findViewById ( R.id.nom_dentist );
                TextAdresse = (TextView)itemView.findViewById ( R.id.adresse_dentist );
                Image=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View itemView) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), DetailsPage.class);

                        // get position
                        int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                        // check if item still exists
                        if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            Dentist clickedDataItem = listArray.get(pos);
                            intent.putExtra("nom",clickedDataItem.getNom ());
                            intent.putExtra("adresse",clickedDataItem.getAdresse ());
                            intent.putExtra ( "image", clickedDataItem.getImage ());
                            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
                });


}
```

**The second activity:**

```
DetailNom = (TextView)findViewById ( R.id.detail_nom );
        DetailsAdresse = (TextView)findViewById ( R.id.detail_adresse );
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById ( R.id.detail_image);
        DetailNom.setText ( "Nom :"+getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "nom" ) );
        DetailsAdresse.setText ( "Adresse :"+getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "adresse" ) );
        imageView.setImageResource ( getIntent ().getIntExtra ( "image", Integer.parseInt ( "00" ) ));
```

Comment: Bcoz your image value are not `int` its `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Picasso or glide or some other library to load image into imageview.

An example:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "image")).into(imageView);
```

Comment: I used Picasso library :                                                                                           public void setImage(String image) {
                Picasso.with ( itemView.getContext () )
                        .load ( image)
                        .into ( Image);
            }                                                                                                            All images of my items are displayed in my recyclerView but when i clicked an item the image is not displayed :the problem is in the intent

Comment: imageView.setImageResource ( getIntent ().getIntExtra ( "image", Integer.parseInt ( "00" ) ));   // here you are not using picasso library right?

Comment: I know but how can i rectify this please ? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using setImageResource()?   This is to set drawable.

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "image")).into(imageView);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "image","00")));
```

Comment: It shows me : " getStringExtra(String) cannott be applied to (String, java.lang.String)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int image = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra(“image”));
imageView.setImageResource(image);
```

Comment: The app is stopped

Answer (score 0):

Use `int` type for Image if your image source is resource Ids.

```
imageView.setImageResource ( getIntent ().getIntExtra ( "image", 0));
```

Use `String` type for image if your image source is URL string.

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "image","00")));
```

Comment: It shows me : " getStringExtra(String)  cannott be applied to (String, java.lang.String)"